# jquery script - values send via ajax and use in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jquery script with two sliders. The values get send via Ajax in my php file:

**html_file.php**

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 25,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            /* Here we send the slider value towards PHP */
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "php_file.php",
                data: { sliderVal: ui.value, sliderVal2: ui2.value2 }   
            })
            /* Here we receive the data back */
            .done(function(data) {
                /* Here you can do whatever you want with the data */
               $("#content").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $("#slider-range-max").slider("value") );
});
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max2" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 4,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount2").val2(ui.value);
            /* Here we send the slider value towards PHP */
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "php_file.php",
                data: { sliderVal: ui.value, sliderVal2: ui2.value2 }  
            })
            /* Here we receive the data back */
            .done(function(data2) {
                /* Here you can do whatever you want with the data */

                $("#content").html(data2);
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#amount2" ).val( $("#slider-range-max2").slider("value2") );
});
```

```
<input type="text" id="amount2" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;   font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-max2"></div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

**php_file.php**

```
<?php    
$str = $_POST['sliderVal'];
$quality = $_POST['sliderVal2'];

$str2 = file_get_contents('https://example.com/stats/258?level='. $str .'&breedId=5&qualityId='. $quality .'&locale=de_DE');

$json = json_decode($str2, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array

$n= $json['health'];

echo '<div class="profile-font2">', $n, '</div>';
?>
```

**The Problem**

Now I have two sliders which changes their values indepently from each other. Here the screenshot to understand it better.

[image]

If I change the second slider (quality) the values of the first slider (level) disappeears. They should be both respected. So in this case of the screenshot there should be the level=6
and the quality=2.

**Still actual.**

Comment: The error seems to be a permission error

Comment: It´s not about the error message. It´s cause i have cut the link. I just want the values "Quality" and "Level" are changed in the link when moving the both sliders. At the moment when I move the second slider the value of the first slider disappears.

Comment: I only see one slider in your markup was that on purpose?

Comment: No there are two sliders in the script. On the screenshot you see both sliders. I need them to be connected.

Comment: I am talking about what you posted to this question.

Comment: You send only one value to the server, that's why the server only "finds" one value. You need to send both values in both ajax requests.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more please. I don´t understand it.

Comment: In our ajax call what you send to the server is at the line `data: { sliderVal2: ui.value }` which means that you only send `ui.value`, but the server needs two values (you only send one)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah I see. So i need to give a the value another name or? So for example if i call it value2 the slider doesn´t work anymore. How to fix that?

Comment: You have to send 2 values to the server for each AJAX call ( data: { sliderVal: ui.value,  sliderVal2: [second_value] } )

Comment: I´ve edited the original post. You mean like that? Sadly it doesn´t work.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? `method: POST` is only `1.9+`

Comment: I´m using 1.12.1